# How to Join two separate text data files and align data over varying time intervals and avg

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, datetime, pandas

I have two text data files from two different instruments. One is an elevator that     raises and lowers at 7 and 8 minute intervals. I need to match up (align) the data from one instrument to the data at the upper and lower position times (duration either 7 or 8 minutes). Below is data from instrument (Picarro) and elevator (AEM):

One issues: Picarro time is recorded in UTC time so it is really 6pm, not midnight, whereas the AEM is beginning at midnight.

Loc_Strt values indicates the position Upper (364) or Lower (233).

**Instrument (Picarro)**

```
Date            Time            NH3_Raw              
2014-06-24      00:00:01.134    3.3844673297E+000  
2014-06-24      00:00:03.210    3.1585870007E+000 
2014-06-24      00:00:05.293    3.2442662514E+000
2014-06-24      00:00:06.812    3.2442662514E+000
2014-06-24      00:00:08.335    3.1064987772E+000`
```

**Elevator(AEM)**

```
TIMESTAMP, RECORD, Loc_Strt, Loc_Cut
"2014-06-24 00:15:22.6",798,233.8,215
"2014-06-24 00:23:22",799,364,378.8
"2014-06-24 00:30:22.5",800,233.7,215.4
"2014-06-24 00:37:21.9",801,364.7,378.8
"2014-06-24 00:45:22.5",802,233.8,215.4
```

I want to be able to merge these two separate files and output into a new list. From this new list, then i want to perform statistical analysis, mean, std dev, etc on the data. But first I must align the data among those time frames. The interval pattern for the AEM appears to be 7,8,8,7 minutes, and then repeats so need to create some loop i assume for this but far beyond my Python skills. I would like to create intervals along this pattern to corroborate the data.

Comment: How can you align dates with 6 days between them? Do you want to sort the values based on the dates?

Comment: The files would be from the same date. I mistakenly typed the wrong dates. I have edited now.

Comment: So, you want to sort them by their time point?

Comment: Yes. I want to average all the Picarro data over the time interval from the Elevator(AEM). I am measuring gas oncentrations at two heights (Upper and Lower), 233 = Lower & 378 = Upper. For example, Picarro is measuring continuously and records a data point ~ 2/seconds. I need to average the Picarro data over the time spent at each height, Upper & Lower. Lower(7 mins), Upper(8mins), Lower(8mins), Upper(7mins), this is the cycle every 30 mins, then loop to repeat. The 21-22 seconds is the travel time of the elevator  to move to the opposite height. I guess you could round down to whole minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method you can use:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# Custom classes to hold your data.
class ElevatorInterval(object):
    def __init__(self, timestamp, record, loc_strt, loc_cut):
        timestamp = datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
        self.timestop = self.timestart = timestamp + timedelta(hours=6) #UTC+6
        self.measures = []
        self.location = 'bottom' if float(loc_strt) < 300 else 'top'
class NH3Measure(object):
    def __init__(self, date, tim, nh3_raw):
        self.timestamp = datetime.strptime(date + tim, "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")
        self.nh3 = nh3_raw
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.nh3)
# Read data from file and assign them to elevator measures, and NH3 measures.
ele_intervals, nh3_measures = [], []
with open('aem.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        linematch = re.match(r'^"([0-9-]+\s[0-9:]+)(?:\.[0-9])?",([0-9]+),([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+)', line)
        if linematch:
            ele_intervals.append(ElevatorInterval(*linematch.groups()))
            if len(ele_intervals) > 1: # Set timestop for the last elevator interval.
                ele_intervals[-2].timestop = ele_intervals[-1].timestart - timedelta(seconds=22)
del ele_intervals[-1] # Remove last interval as it has no stop time.
with open('pic.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        linematch = re.match(r'^([0-9-]+)\s+([0-9:]+)[0-9.]*\s+([0-9E.+]+)', line)
        if linematch: nh3_measures.append(NH3Measure(*linematch.groups()))
# Assign NH3 measures to their proper interval, and output the intervals.
for ele in ele_intervals:
    ele.measures = filter(lambda x: ele.timestart < x.timestamp < ele.timestop, nh3_measures)
    print ele.location, ele.measures
```

With the sample input, `aem.txt`:

```
TIMESTAMP, RECORD, Loc_Strt, Loc_Cut
"2014-06-23 18:15:22.6",798,233.8,215
"2014-06-23 18:23:22",799,364,378.8
"2014-06-23 18:30:22.5",800,233.7,215.4
"2014-06-23 18:37:22.5",801,364,378.8
```

And `pic.txt`:

```
Date            Time            NH3_Raw              
2014-06-24      00:16:39.134    3.3844673297E+000  
2014-06-24      00:16:41.210    3.1585870007E+000 
2014-06-24      00:16:43.293    3.2442662514E+000
2014-06-24      00:24:45.293    4.2442662514E+000
2014-06-24      00:24:47.812    4.4242662514E+000
2014-06-24      00:24:49.335    4.1064987772E+000
2014-06-24      00:31:45.293    3.2442662514E+000
2014-06-24      00:31:47.812    3.2442662514E+000
2014-06-24      00:31:49.335    3.1064987772E+000
```

Prints the result:

```
bottom [3.3844673297E+000, 3.1585870007E+000, 3.2442662514E+000]
top [4.2442662514E+000, 4.4242662514E+000, 4.1064987772E+000]
bottom [3.2442662514E+000, 3.2442662514E+000, 3.1064987772E+000]
```

Comment: where you used'with open('pic.txt', 'r') as f:', I am trying to use with pd.read_csv(file, header=0, index_col=0) as f: but keep getting an __exit__ attribute error. Any ideas why? Picarro file is a fixed width file (fwf) and the AEM is a csv. I wanted to use pandas because they have simple module read_fwf and read_csv to handle each file type. Please help

Comment: I don't know much about those modules, sorry. Maybe you should open another question. However, you can try [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), which is amazing.

Comment: THE AEM (elevator) example file i provided has many more columns than just the three i provided in the text. When trying to import it into your script, i get the following error: __init__ takes exactly 5 arguments, only 4 given

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jason\Google Drive\Python Programs\AEM_Picarro_Slice", line 23, in <module>
    ele_intervals.append(ElevatorInterval(*linematch.groups()))
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)

Comment: Try printing `linematch.groups()`. With my code it should return a tuple with 4 elements. You have changed it somehow so it only gives three.